Would a student have any valid claim to freedom of speech if a school prevented him giving out condoms?
I re-stumbled upon an older story that even the first time I read it had me questioning if the student in it had any legal case for his threat to sue here
The story is long but the short version is that a student was sharing condoms and information about birth control in a school that taught abstinence only sex ed, which the principal didn't approve of.  The school created a rule that one couldn't congregate at lunch tables they weren't assigned to which was allegedly enforced selectively only to make those who came to the student for information/condoms sit down as a way to skirt free speech laws.
Then the student gets a bunch of people to put out bowls of candy for a little while before putting out a bowl of condoms.  When he is pressured to stop putting out condoms he threatens to sue on the grounds that his free speech was silenced, supposedly their allowing free candy to be put out showed their problem was the condoms and that was preventing his free speech?
This claim seemed flimsy to me, while the boy has the right to talk about birth control, even distribute pamphlets on the topic, I don't think freedom of speech would stretch so far as to allow one to insist they be able to hand out items like condoms when the primary motive was not speech but for people to use the items?  It seems the student would have more room to allege first amendment violation with the allegedly selectively enforced rules about talking to people at other lunch tables; but it seems like it would be rather hard to prove selective enforcement.
If this had gone to a court would the student have had any legal leg to stand on?

I don't have time for a full answer, but I'd say your take is largely correct. There may have been a selective-enforcement case regarding the anti-congregation rule, but a court would likely not view condom distribution as sufficiently expressive to merit a First Amendment analysis.

@bdb484 such an analysis would probably include consideration of the age of the students to which the condoms are being distributed.  I don't find it likely that distributing them to 8-year-olds would be protected; 18-year-olds far more likely; 14-to-17-year-olds I'm not sure about.

@phoog If the court found the conduct expressive, then yes, that would be an important part of the analysis. I think most courts would not get that far, though.

@bdb484 oh I see, I missed a "not" in your comment.  Justice Douglas disagrees with you.

I think you're overreading his opinion. In any event, I think we can agree that his concurring opinion isn't the law.


I don't think freedom of speech would stretch so far as to allow one to insist they be able to hand out items like condoms when the primary motive was not speech but for people to use the items?

The Supreme Court has interpreted "speech" very broadly to include expressive actions of many sorts.  The Wikipedia article has a section on expressive conduct.  In 1972, in Eisenstadt v. Baird, the court overturned a conviction for distributing contraceptive foam (by someone other than a medical professional to someone who is unmarried).  The case turned primarily on equal protection, because because the court had already established that married people had a right to contraception, but Justice Douglas's concurring opinion does discuss free speech:

First Amendment rights are not limited to verbal expression. [Footnote 2/5] The right to petition often involves the right to walk. The right of assembly may mean pushing or jostling. Picketing involves physical activity, as well as a display of a sign. A sit-in can be a quiet, dignified protest that has First Amendment protection even though no speech is involved, as we held in Brown v. Louisiana, supra. Putting contraceptives on display is certainly an aid to speech and discussion. Handing an article under discussion to a member of the audience is a technique known to all teachers, and is commonly used. A handout may be on such a scale as to smack of a vendor's marketing scheme. But passing one article to an audience is merely a projection of the visual aid, and should be a permissible adjunct of free speech.


Example of nonverbal speech: The black armband in Tinker vs De Moines

Your implication seems to be that you believe that handing out condoms could constitute free speech, but you don't say that directly.  I feel the answer would be easier read if you first spell out what you are claiming before jumping into the evidence.

@dsollen I think the only argument phoog is making is that the cited SCOTUS jurisprudence does not reach a clear conclusion/precedent on the 1st amendment aspects of the conduct in question. There is a concurring dicta that implies such would exist, but that is not a binding part of the decision.

Does the school receive government funding?
If it doesn’t, then it is not an arm of government and the First Amendment doesn’t apply.
But that’s boring, so let’s assume it does.
He certainly has an arguable case
The school is certainly entitled to introduce rules (like lunch seating arrangements and limiting free stuff handouts), however, to the extent that these limit Constitutional rights, they must pass strict scrutiny:

the law or regulation is necessary to achieve a "compelling state [school] interest". The government [school] must also demonstrate that the law is "narrowly tailored" to achieve that compelling purpose, and that it uses the "least restrictive means" to achieve that purpose.

In addition, for free speech limits, the restriction must generally be content neutral.
The selective implementation and restrictions seriously undermines this. Indeed, they would have been far better off banning the sex-Ed talk and condom distribution specifically as against a compelling school interest.

Hilariously incorrect. "Your honor, I failed the plaintiff because he got every single question wrong on the final." "Sorry, pal, you can't punish students for false speech without satisfying strict scrutiny."

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
